# Use programs installed on Docker base image

Tags: gcc, makefile, docker, dockerfile

This is something that's been bugging me for a while, but how come I can't access programs that are installed in my base image in my Docker image?

For example, my base image has make & gcc installed. However, in my current image that I am accessing via `docker run`, I can't access make or gcc despite having `FROM base img` . I get `bash: make: command not found`.

Comment: show us your `Dockerfile`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are running `run` command with correct format. E.g.:

```
docker run -it python:3.4.3-slim python --version

               IMAGE^^^^^^^^^^^^ COMMAND ^^^^^^^^
```